# JSF ajax commandbutton from multiple forms within same page reinitiliazes the viewscoped bean

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

changeThe page has 2 forms. In the first form, the ajax-button initializes an attribute of the viewscoped managed bean. In the second form, the ajax-button uses that attribute to do some stuff. 
Problem is that the method called by the second form button never gets invoked. Instead, the viewscoped bean is re-initialized and when I hit the same button again, of course the attribute is null resulting in NPE.
When I put the 2 buttons within the same form, then everything works as expected.
Is this normal: should ajax enabled buttons always reside within the same form?

```
<h:form id="frmDetail">    
    <h:commandButton  id="btn_changePlant" title="#{msg.ttChangePlant}" immediate="true"  image="/resources/img/edit.png">
        <f:ajax event="click" render=":fsDetailPlant :headerMsg"  listener="{assortiment.detailPlantId}"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
...some other code ...
<h:form id="frmOffers">    
    <h:commandButton  id="btn_offers" title="#{msg.ttOfferPlant}" immediate="true"  value="#{msg.btn_offers}">
        <f:ajax event="click" render=":fsDetailPlant :headerMsg"  listener="{assortiment.changeOffers}"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

and the managed bean looks like

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Assortiment extends BeanObject implements Serializable {
    ....

public void detailPlantId(AjaxBehaviorEvent actionEvent) {
    clear();
    plantdetail = facade.findPlantdetail(plantdetailsIdModel.getRowData());
}

  public void changeOffers(AjaxBehaviorEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("........ Assortiment.changeOffers(AjaxBehaviorEvent actionEvent)");
    if (containerItems.isEmpty()) {
        SessieUtils.fillPropertyItems(containerItems, PlantProperty.codeValuesList(ECodeType.logistic, "L02"), facade.getLocale());
    }
    //
    if (offersModel == null) {
        offersModel = new ListDataModel<OffersDto>(plantdetail.getOffersList());
    }
}
```

Comment: @memetech, indeed, the # is missing in my post. If I put lines in comment, I always have to remove the # signs, otherwise the expression is still evaluated. Anyhow, that isn't the cause of the problem. Without changing anything on the serverside, as soon as both buttons are placed within the same form, everything works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that the listener attributes need the # prefix,

```
listener="{assortiment.changeOffers}"
```

should be

```
listener="#{assortiment.changeOffers}"
```